# How to call twofunction in componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I failed to call two funtion in componentDidMount.When I clicked bangla its change and when i clicke english its change but during routing it stays only english so i wanted to set the state in componentDidMount,but it only invoke one funtion.if click the bangla it set bangla but when i change the routing its remain the same lang. so how can i set it.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import {setLanguage} from "../../actions";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

    class MenuComp extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.setLang = this.setLang.bind(this);
            this.state= {
                "maintitle": {
                    "titlelist": [
                        {"title1":"Timetable"},
                        {"title2":"Ticket Prices"},
                        {"title3":"About Us"}
                    ]
                }
            };
        }

        setLang(lang){
            this.props.setLanguage(lang);
            this.props.history.push('/menu');
        }
        changeLanguage = () => {
            this.setState({
                "maintitle": {
                    "titlelist": [
                        {"title1":"সময়সূচী"},
                        {"title2":"টিকেটর মূল্য"},
                        {"title3":"আমাদের সম্পর্কে"}
                    ]
                }
            });
         };
         changeLang = () => {
            this.setState({
                "maintitle": {
                    "titlelist": [
                        {"title1":"Timetable"},
                        {"title2":"Ticket Prices"},
                        {"title3":"About Us"}
                    ]
                }
            });
         };

         componentDidMount() {
            this.changeLanguage();
           this.changeLang();
          }

        render() {

            return (
                <div className="Menu">
                <div className="menu-header">
                <div className="container-fluid p-0">
                    <div className="row m-0">
                        <div className="col-md-4 p-0 d-flex justify-content-end">
                            <div className="align-self-center">
                                <a className="lang" onClick={() => { this.setLang('bn'); this.changeLanguage(); }}>Bangla</a> | 
                                <a className="lang l-active" onClick={() => { this.setLang('en'); this.changeLang(); }}>English</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <main className="navigation">
                <div className="container-fluid p-0">
                    <div className="row m-0">

                        <div className="col-md-4 pl-0">
                            <Link to="/timetable" className="lang">
                                <div className="card-content">                             
                                    <h6 className="card-title">{
                                        this.state.maintitle.titlelist.map((title, i)=>{
                                            return (<p key={i}>{title.title1} </p>)
                                        })
                                    }</h6>
                                </div>
                            </Link>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-md-4 pl-0">
                            <Link to="/ticketprice" className="lang">
                                <div className="card-content">
                                    <h6 className="card-title">{
                                        this.state.maintitle.titlelist.map((title, i)=>{
                                            return (<p key={i}>{title.title2} </p>)
                                        })
                                    }</h6>
                                </div>
                            </Link>
                        </div>

                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
                </div>

            );
        }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state){
        return {
            lang: state.lang.lang
        }
    }
    const Menu = connect(mapStateToProps, {setLanguage})(withRouter(MenuComp));


    export default Menu;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an asynchronous problem. So, the `setState` method runs asynchronously. This makes reading `this.state` right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall.

So, the lines inside your `componentDidMount` method get executed, however, you can't predict which one of them will finish before the other.

Now, I don't completely understand what you're trying to achieve, but instead, use `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState` callback `(setState(updater, callback))`: something like this:

```
this.setState((state, props)=> ({
            "maintitle": {
                "titlelist": [
                    {"title1":"সময়সূচী"},
                    {"title2":"টিকেটর মূল্য"},
                    {"title3":"আমাদের সম্পর্কে"}
                ]
            }
        }), ()=> {// do what you want next!})
// (this could be inside your componentDidMount!
```

If that didn't help, please let me know!